# LocalFileSystem is not defined PhoneGap (Build) in Android

Tags: android, cordova

I have the following code:

```
function wait(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //alert("Dentro de ready");
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", init(), true);
    });
}
```

Where "wait" is a Javascript function called from the  onload event. I use the onload event, as well as $(document).ready and "deviceready" event to make sure every single thing is loaded when i start coding.

The "init()" method does a few things and then calls the following method:

```
function download_img(imgToDownload){
    var url = remote_url+imgToDownload; // image url
    alert("img url: "+url);     
    try{
    window.requestFileSystem(**LocalFileSystem**.PERSISTENT, 0, 
            function (fs) {
        var imagePath = fs.root.fullPath +"/"+ imgToDownload; // full file path
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        fileTransfer.download(url, imagePath, 
            function (entry) {
            alert("OK: " + entry.fullPath); // entry is fileEntry object
            }, 
            function (error) {
                alert("download error source " + error.source);
            alert("download error target " + error.target);
            alert("upload error code" + error.code);
            alert("http_status"+error.http_status);
            }
        );
        }
    );
    }catch(err){
    alert(err.message);
    }
}
```

Where I get the error message: "LocalFileSystem is not defined".

My config.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.lamakun.mancomunidad"
    version   = "3.0.0">

<name>PhoneGap Build Application</name>

<description>
A simple PhoneGap Build application.
</description>

<author href="https://example.com" email="you@example.com">
Your Name
</author>
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.2.0" />


<access origin="http://www.mytests.es" subdomains="true"/>

</widget>
```

In case I might add any permission, even though I think right now I have them all.
Can anyone give me a clue on that?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", init(), true);
```

it should be:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, true);
```

having the () after init calls that function immediately before the deviceready event is fired.

Comment: Thanks Simon but if I don't use the brackets "init" is not called (I have an alert which does not appear without brackets). Do you know why? What about using "function(){init();}". Thanks again!

Comment: Ivan, if you do document.addEventListener("deviceready", init(), true); then the init method will be called immediately upon parsing. It will not wait until the deviceready event is fired. If you try to call PhoneGap methods before the deviceready event you will get the error you described. Your real problem seems to be you are not getting the deviceready event. If I were you I'd take the call to $(document).ready out of your wait method and call it after the other script tags are loaded.

Comment: To be honest I don't realy know what you mean by "call it after the other script tags are loaded". When should I call  $(document).ready? I have also seen you have an article about getting the deviceready to fire faster. I am working with phonegap which I think has a timeout for the app to load. Is it possible my deviceready takes longer than the timeout?

Comment: Ok, finally, after a few hours of sleep, reducing my app to its minimum expression, I found out that I needed to add the cordova.js (with no version suffix) in my index.html for phonegap build to wrap it properly. Sorry for the inconveniences but it is my first phonegap/build app and I took for granted that PGB was including the proper js for each device. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

write these lines in android manifiest file

Comment: For me also same problem. I used 'WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' permission on android manifiest file. Used "cordova" version is 2.8.1