# Reference Error: LocalFileSystem not defined

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

i am trying to create a file in my worklight project using cordova File API. I am getting the error,

> Reference Error: LocalFileSystem not defined

I tried using the solution in the following link but still i get the same error. Should i add any script files in my js folder? i am not sure where to get the exact cordova.js file from.
[PhoneGap- Android FileSystem Requesting Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845244/localfilesystem-is-not-defined-phonegap-build-in-android)

When i included the cordova.js file , i am getting the error 
[image]

here is my code:

```
    document.addEventListener("ondeviceready", onDeviceReady(), true);
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
}

function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    alert(fileSystem.name+" created");
    alert(fileSystem.root.name);
}

function fail(evt) {
    alert(evt.target.error.code);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share your code? Make sure that you are using LocalFileSystem after deviceready event is fired.

Comment: i have updated with my code in the question.. pls let me knw if you want any other information further...

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener("ondeviceready", onDeviceReady(), true);
```

This is wrong. It means you put the return of that function as the argument. You just need to put the name of the function. Use this instead. (without () )

```
document.addEventListener("ondeviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
```

Comment: i have the same issue here. my config.xml is well setup

Comment: i think you've got to add <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/cordova.js"></script> to ur index file. as sggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845244/localfilesystem-is-not-defined-phonegap-build-in-android

Answer (score 0):

maybe you didn't install the file system plugin, try after **cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file** command.